# Need to replace "comma" with 'dot'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help me to adjust an existing script to replace COMMA with DOT.
I use a script which limit the inserting character into Text fields. Only 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 and "." and "," are accepted to be inserted. I would like to have two buttons of inserting DOT - key==188 (comma) and key== 190 (dot).

```
jQuery.fn.ForceNumericOnly =
    function()
    {
        return this.each(function()
        {
            $(this).keydown(function(e)
            {
                var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
                return (
                    key == 8 || 
                    key == 9 ||
                    key == 46 ||
                    key == 110 ||
                    key == 188 ||   
                    key == 190 ||
                    (key >= 35 && key <= 40) ||
                    (key >= 48 && key <= 57) ||
                    (key >= 96 && key <= 105));

            });
        });
    };
$("#iMONEY").ForceNumericOnly();
```

It can be tested [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/WfpEu/6/)

Comment: It is not clear what problem you're having.

Comment: I do not know how to replace COMMA with DOT...

Comment: It is easy to give up from COMMA, but I would like to have ACTIVE button COMMA but inserting DOT

Comment: I think it'd be easier to catch "keypress" and simply replace any commas in the field value with dots.

Comment: I honestly would avoid such approach, unless it's okay to you don't replace comma with dot if the user paste a text with comma in the text field (using keyboard or mouse). Same it's applying for drag & drop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use

```
if(e.keyCode == 188){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).val($(this).val() + '.');
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/WfpEu/8/) you go. :)

For future references [Mini-Tutorial](http://www.kristofdegrave.be/2012/03/javascript-change-entered-character-in.html).

Comment: It'd also be necessary to prevent the default action of the keydown event.

Comment: Also that jsfiddle link doesn't look any different from the OP.

Comment: Due to some problems the fiddle did not update. And @Pointy, next time learn to use the edit feature.

Comment: I'll fix minor typos, but you're in charge of the substance of your answers.

Answer (score 2):

The value of the textbox is updated ***after*** keypress event is fired. It's not a place to replace comma with dot. Use keyup event instead:

```
jQuery.fn.ForceNumericOnly =
    function()
    {
       this.keyup(function(e)
            {
//                console.log("Change");
                $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/,/g,"."));
            });
    };
$("#iMONEY").ForceNumericOnly();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WfpEu/9/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
// 110 is numpad comma code
if (key === 188 && key === 110) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).val($(this).val() + '.');                   
}
```

Comment: Maybe because this code doesn't prevent the default action of the "keypress" event.

Comment: @Pointy, why should it?

Comment: If it doesn't, then the browser will *also* add the comma!

Comment: well I only say this because I coded up this exact same bug some years ago :)  I will try it now; perhaps something's changed or perhaps my memory's faulty!

Comment: [Here is a jsbin with code that I think to be essentially equivalent.](http://jsbin.com/axoqoZe/1) I get both a "." and a "," when I type "," in the box.

Comment: @Pointy, it is certainly NOT equivalent. `this.value += '.'` is not equal to `$(this).val($(this).val() + '.')`

Comment: yes it is. It's the same as `this.value = this.value + '.';` and that is the same as the jQuery code. I can change it but it'll do the same thing. (Feel free to try it yourself.)

Comment: @Pointy, I don't know where you've taken your code and why it adds the  comma. The code exactly the same as mine was accepted by OP as correct answer, so I don't understand the point of downvote.

Comment: In the jsfiddle in that accepted answer, the person who gave the answer added a call to `e.preventDefault()` to make sure that the default action doesn't happen. Did you not try the jsbin I linked? [Here is a version that uses jQuery to update the value.](http://jsbin.com/axoqoZe/2)

Comment: Ok, I see now, thanks. The person should have also added preventDefault to the answer on SO

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Replace method

```
var someVariable = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0";
$mylabel.text( someVariable.replace(',', '.') );
```

**EDIT:**
If you are checking from TextBox then do it like this:

```
if(Key == 188){
   var someVariable =  $("#TEXTBOXID").val();
    somVariable = someVariable.replace(',', '.');
}
```

Comment: it is not like this... by pressing KEY=188 which is comma need to replace with DOT

Comment: See my Edit. Hope it helps.

Comment: Doing this in "keydown" is a bad idea.